# Creating new AVPlayer while in background does not work?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm playing music with an `AVPlayer`. Now at a certain time a `NSTimer` fires and I'dlike to fade over to another track. So I start fading out my AVPlayer and create a new AVPlayer instance to play the next song.

When on foreground this works as expected. But when my app is on background. The playing track fades out but the new `AVPlayer` instance does not start playing. Is it just not possible to create a new AVPlayer instance on background? or how can I make it play? Or is there another way to overlap two tracks?

I could do the playback with `AVQeueuPalyer`, but then I can't let tracks overlap. Any suggestions?

-- EDIT --

If it was not clear, I am able to play background audio as long as I want. Just creating a new AVPlayer instance in background does not work.

Comment: I still need to know how to run AVPlayer from background :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do what I wanted seems to be AVMutableComposition. With that I don't need multiple AVPlayers and a few other benefits. For more details: I summarized it in a blogpost: http://www.postblog.me/2012/03/playing-multiple-overlapping-audio-tracks-in-background/

Comment: I’m playing video with AVplayer... it works well also in the background, it plays the audio. However if I pause the first AVplayer and start a second one, it just won’t play in the background. I’m wondering if having two or more instances alive in iOS just isn’t supported very well when it comes to background play. Maybe I need to just change the url/avplayeritem of the first AVplayer. Sorry, just my thoughts...

Comment: Blogpost is a dead link

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a key named "UIBackgroundModes" (array) to your app's Info.plist and add the value "audio" inside it. Then call

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];
```

And then you should be able to play audio in the background (you should link to the AVFoundation framework).

Comment: Sorr if I was not precise enough, but playing background audio itself is not the issue. I have your suggested parts already in my app. Only creating and playing a new AVPlayer while in background does not work.

Comment: And then it seems that you simply can't do it.